# git ls-tree HEAD - meaning of third column

Tags: git, tree

What does the string in the third column mean when we do

```
$ git ls-tree HEAD
```

like so

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third column is the key of the objects contained the tree that you are currently seeing.

Git stores all the information it handles in a key-value storage, the key being the hashes that you see printed with `ls-tree` or the hash that is created when a commit happens.

There are three kind of objects git saves: commits, trees, and blobs.

You can access the contents of any of the objects that git has stored with the command `git cat-file <hash>`. For example the following command (`-p` for pretty printing) will print the contents of your commit object which should look similar to this:

```
> git cat-file -p HEAD
tree def456aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
parent f1ddfa625b139184e8b719fcb662e713a77fedcb
author Bob Foo <bob@foo.com> 1358366479 -0800
committer Bob Foo <bob@foo.com> 1358366479 -0800

The commit message.
```

The contents of the tree object that is displayed there (the assumed `def456...`) is exactly what you see when using `git ls-tree HEAD`. So if you use the following command you should see exactly the same output:

```
> git cat-file -p def456aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
# the same output as: git ls-tree HEAD
```

With the hashes displayed there you can keep doing the same. If you use it with a blob object it will print the contents of the file, if you use it with a tree object, it will display the contents of the tree, which would be a subdirectory in your repository. For example to see the current contents of the `contact.html` file you can use:

```
> git cat-file -p 2271a9
# contents in contact.html
```

Lastly, check [Git Internals - Git Objects](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) for more information about all this.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that it's the unique 40-character sha1 hash ID of each object contained in the given tree in the Git repository, though [the documentation for `git ls-tree`](https://www.kernel.org/pub//software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-tree.html#_output_format) doesn't really make that clear, and only refers to the 3rd column as `<object>`:

> ### Output Format
>
> ```
> <mode> SP <type> SP <object> TAB <file>
> ```

Comment: As far as know 40-character SHA-1 hash Id is only generated for each comment. Is it created for each file and folder in repo?